# For millions of objects, is it better to store in an array or a database like redis if the objects are needed in realtime?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, storage, redis, simulation

I am developing a simulation in which there can be millions of entities that can interact with each other. At the moment, all the entities are stored in a list. Would it be better to store the objects in a database like redis instead of a list?

Answer (score 2):

**Note:** I assumed this was being implemented in Java (force of habit).  My answer is not  terribly useful if it is not Java.

Making lots of assumptions about your requirements, I'd consider Redis if:

- You are running into unacceptable GC pauses as a result of your millions of objects OR
- The entities you create can be reused across multiple simulation runs

Java apps with giant heaps and lots of long-lived objects can run into very long GC pauses, depending on work-load.  i.e. the old gen fills up with all these millions of objects and they're never eligible for collection.  Regardless, periodically a full collect will happen (unless you're a GC tuning master) and have to scan these millions of objects in the old gen. This can take many seconds each time it happens, and you're frozen during that time.  If this is happening and you don't like it, you could off-load all these long-lived objects to Redis, and pay the serialize/deserialize cost of accessing them rather than the GC pauses.

On the other point about reusing entities: if you're loading up a big Redis db and then dropping all its data when the simulation ends, it feels a bit wasteful.  If you can re-use entities across simulation runs you might save yourself a bunch of time by persisting them in Redis.

Comment: An example would be of a Grid 10,000 by 10,000 with 1,000,000 entities moving around. At the moment there is an implementation in javascript using the canvas element to draw it. I was wondering if there are any kind of memory leaks with larger arrays. I am hoping to further optimise the implementation using a quad tree structure. GC?

Comment: Haha, I assumed Java not Javascript :)  I'll note that assumption in my answer.  You might want to mention in the question and/or tags that you're using Javascript.

Answer (score 2):

The best choice depends on a number of factors, including how you access data, whether it will fit in memory, and what the distribution of accesses looks like. As a broad generalization, keeping data in memory is always faster than on disk, and keeping it in-process is faster than keeping it elsewhere.

If your data fits in memory, is accessed in a manner that means you can use basic data structures like lists/arrays and hashtables efficiently, and all items are accessed roughly equally often, keeping your data in memory is probably the best option.

If your data fits in memory, but you need to access it in complex ways, you may be best choosing a datastore like redis that supports in-memory databases.

If your data doesn't fit in memory, or you have a very uneven access pattern such that evicting the least used data to disk might allow other things to be loaded, speeding up your task in general, a regular disk-based datastore may be a better choice.

Answer (score 0):

A list is not necessarily the best data structure unless "interaction" is limited to the respective next or previous element. Random access (by index) is very slow on a list.
Lists rocket at inserting at front and end, and at finding the next (or previous) element, or inserting one in between. They *totally blow* for accessing element 164553 and then element 10657, being O(N) on random access. Thus "interact *with each other*" suggests that list is a bad choice.

It very much depends on the access and allocation patterns, but a `vector` or `deque` will likely be much better suited than a list for your simulation.

Redis is based on a hash table, which has a (much!) better characteristic for random access, but it will most likely *still* be slower, because it has considerable overhead for you serializing the data, it going through a socket, redis unserializing and analyzing it, sending a reply, and you parsing that.

Comment: You seem to be assuming a particular meaning for 'list'. In Python, `list` is the name for arrays. In Java, it's an interface that supports indexed access, and may or may not be efficient for that depending on the underlying class. In Erlang, a list actually is a linked list, but that's far from being the general case.

Comment: @Nick Johnson: Assuming that `list` without mention of a language really means either "linked list" or "doubly linked list" is reasonable, unless something else is explicitly said. Assuming that this is not the case just because the implementer of some particular language named his construct _wrong_ is silly. Linked list is a well-known data structure with well-known properties (as are vectors or if you want to call them "arrays"). Besides, if you had read the comment to overthink's answer (after my answer, but well before yours), you would know that the OP is using Javascript.

Comment: I don't think that _is_ a reasonable assumption - as I pointed out, the term is used interchangeably with array in several languages. `List` on its own doesn't imply `linked` - see the Wikipedia page (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_(computer_science)) for more examples. I'm also pretty skeptical that the OP really meant they had implemented a linked list in Javascript.

Comment: Sorry guys, I was wondering about this problem in the general case. I am trying to implement this in both javascript and python and meant list in the most general sense like a simple array